# AdminService.log "Adding DOMAIN\USERNAME to local group WSS_WPG" every minute

Tags: 2016

We are in process of building a new SharePoint 2016 farm and one of the things we've come across is inside the AdminService.log it lists this every minute

```
10/23/2018 7:59:54 AM    TagId=959866484    Pid=12908    ThrdId=60    Level=Medium    Category=msoulscat_WSS_Topology    --    Adding DOMAIN\USERNAME to local group WSS_WPG.
```

I've verified that the user it is trying to add to WSS_WPG is already in the group. It sounds like it's some sort of security issue for an account somewhere, but I'm not sure what.

Any idea what would cause this to constantly try to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a security issue, but the admin service that loops through the appropriate accounts (e.g. Farm Admins, Managed service accounts) and just adds them. It doesn't assume or perform a delta of membership which is why you see Add User each time.